# How to replace a particular string in c# using regex or linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string where I need to replace a particular string, my string is as follows

```
string s = @"-Username ABC **-Password XYZ** -Address MNO";
string[] s1 = s.Split('-');
var newList = s1.Where(s2 =>s2.Contains("Password"));
```

I need to replace the string `-Password XYZ` to `-Password ****` can some one help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test

```
    [TestCase("-Username ABC -Password XYZ -Address MNO", "-Username ABC -Password *** -Address MNO")]
    [TestCase("-Username ABC -Password XYZ", "-Username ABC -Password ***")]
    public void Test(string toTest, string expected ) 
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, DestroyPassword(toTest));
    }
```

Code

```
    public static string DestroyPassword(string str )
    {
          var r = new Regex("-Password .*?($| )");//? in .net means not greedy
          return r.Replace(str, "-Password ***$1");
    }
```

EDIT:

Word of caution

This doesn't mask passwords with spaces in them. If you know that `-Address` is always the next token then something like this will be better:

```
    public static string DestroyPassword(string str )
    {
        var r = new Regex("-Password .*?($| -Address)");//? in .net means not greedy
        return r.Replace(str, "-Password ***$1");
    }
```

but event that doesn't deal well with the case when the password contains '-Address'

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex.Replace(input, replacement). Function will replace all values found by regex expression.

```
string input = @"-Username ABC **-Password XYZ** -Address MNO";
string pattern = "(-Password )(\S+)";
string replacement = "$1****";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string result = regex.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Comment: My result as per your code `-Username ABC ****** -Address MNO` expected is `-Username ABC -Password ****** -Address MNO`

Comment: This gets rid of the whole '-Password XYZ** ' chuck.

Comment: You're missing @ before the pattern. :)